# Erro em update sql: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query

Estou realizando uma query para alterar o custo liquido de um produto conforme uma marca, porém, recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression. The statement has been terminated.

Eu tentei:

```
UPDATE cd_pro
SET CustoLiquido = ((10 * p.CustoLiquido) / 100) + p.CustoLiquido
FROM cd_pro p
  INNER JOIN cd_marcas m
  ON (p.id_marca = m.id_marca)
  WHERE m.id_marca = 1
```

Comment: A query `SELECT p.CustoLiquido FROM cd_pro p INNER JOIN cd_marcas ON (p.id_marca = m.id_marca) WHERE m.id_marca = 1` está retornando mais de um valor, logo não tem como fazer o UPDATE usando a operação `((10 * p.CustoLiquido) / 100) + p.CustoLiquido`. Refatore a sua query para retornar apenas 1 valor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faz direto:

```
UPDATE cd_pro
SET CustoLiquido = ((10 * CustoLiquido) / 100) + CustoLiquido
WHERE id_marca = 1
```

Como você quer fazer pela marca e você tem o id_marca na tabela cd_pro, nao precisará fazer o join.